# What can we say about $N_{i}$ where $N=N_{1}+\cdots+N_{m}$, $N\thicksim Geom(\frac{1-p}{p})$ and conditional distribution of $N_{j}$ is binomial.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Suppose that the number of events $N$ is a Geometric random variable
with mean $\frac{1-p}{p}$. Further suppose that each event can be classified into one of $m$ types with probabilities $p_{1},p_{2},\ldots,p_{m}$ independent of all other events. Then we consider the number of events $N_{1},N_{2},\ldots,N_{m}$ corresponding to event types $1,2,\ldots,m$, respectively,

***What can we say about $N_{i}$?***

***What is the distribution of $N_{i}$?***

***Are  $N_{1},N_{2},\ldots,N_{m}$ mutually independent  random variables?***

***What is the sign of $cov(N_{1},N_{2})$?***

**My attepmt:**
For fixed $N=n$, the conditional joint distribution of $(N_{1},\ldots,N_{m})$ is
multinomial with parameters $(n,p_{1},\ldots,p_{m})$. Also, for fixed $N=n$, the conditional marginal distribution of $N_{j}$ is binomial with parameters $(n,p_{j})$.

I want to show that the joint pf is the product of the marginal pfs, establishing mutual independence

The joint pf of $(N_{1},\ldots,N_{m})$ is given by

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(N_{1}=n_{1},\ldots,N_{m}=n_{m}) &= \mathbb{P}(N_{1}=n,\ldots,N_{m}=n_{m}|N=n)\mathbb{P}(N=n)\\
&= \left( \frac{n!}{n_{1}!\cdots n_{m}!}p_{1}^{n_{1}}\cdots p_{m}^{n_{m}}\right)(1-p)^{n}p \\
&= \mbox{I do not know how to continue}
\end{align}
 where $n=n_{1}+n_{2}+\cdots +n_{m}$. Similarly, as I fail with the above, try to calculate the marginal pf of $N_{j}$

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(N_{j}=n_{j}) &= \sum_{n=n_{j}}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(N_{j}=n_{j}|N=n)\mathbb{P}(N=n)\\
&= \sum_{n=n_{j}}^{\infty} \binom{n}{n_{j}}p_{j}^{n_{j}}(1-p_{j})^{n-n_{j}}p(1-p)^{n}  \\
&= \mbox{I do not know how to continue}
\end{align}

Comment: Cross-post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/393797/119261.